# Is storing constant enum values in the ServletContext via setAttribute a good or bad idea?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a java web application running under tomcat. In this application, we have a lot of constant dropdowns (where the same values and the same dropdown appears on multiple pages). So maybe we have a drop-down for user-type (full-time, part-time, contractor, temporary). These values for the user-type are stored in an enum. We currently have to manually load the values of the enum for each page that uses it. We might have 10-15 pages that need to display the user-type dropdown values.

We were thinking about adding some of these constant enum values to the ServletContext through setAttribute. The advantage of doing this is that all of the constant drop-down values would be available everywhere without manually adding it to the page and it would be updated in one central place.

The downside is that we're worried that adding enums to the context would create a performance implication. How does tomcat store context attributes? In our case, sessions are stored in a jdbc database and it is a severe performance problem to store anything in the session (since our database server is super slow).

Is it considered a good or bad practice to store constant enum values in the [ServletContext via setAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)? If it is a bad practice, what is a good alternative (other than manually adding the constant to each page that needs it)? Are there any other negative side effects of using the setAttribute on ServletContext?

Thanks!

Comment: this sounds a little discussion-y at the moment. Any specifics, like code or etc? Asking point-blank "is XYZ bad practice" leads to open-ended answers generally

Comment: @Coffee - I could take my userTypeEnum example and write a class example and then show ServletContext.setAttribute("allUserTypes", UserTypeEnum.values()), but I don't know if that would add much value to the question. I suppose I was mostly looking to see if this was a known anti-pattern that I should avoid.

Comment: This link seems relev.  - http://www.coderanch.com/t/360017/Servlets/java/Servlet-Context-database-connection

Comment: @Coffee - thanks for the link, but that user is doing something quite different. They are storing a database connection in the servlet context. I understand why storing a temporary database connection in the context could be problematic and race condition prone. I'm asking about storing constants in the context (i.e. - available colors are red/yellow/green - if we later want to add blue to the list, I can change the code in one place and blue is added everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose an enum is

```
 enum aEnum {s1, s2, s3}
```

Then u can get all the values like this.

```
aEnum.values();
```

Loop over it as

```
 Arrays.asList(aEnum.values()).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));    }
```

If session implemnetation is very fast, It is not any problem if you store it in session. But as you sayed, session is stored in a database. Every time you retrieve a value, a database query is called which is an IO operation and may slow down your page load time. Avoiding unnecessary query is better for performance.